# How can I use my iphone to take inventory without an internet connection?

Tags: osx, inventory, voice-recording, voice-recognition

I have a tree farm.  There is effectively  no internet in the field.  (Phone does see a tower.  Text messages take 1 to 15 minutes, just checking email for new messages takes over a minute.

I would like to do something like this on my iphone:

20,000 trees:

Looking for a way to dictate my inventory taking.

No bar codes in use.

Situation 1:  Blocks of similar trees.
Count them  range of heights that covers 90%.  Estimate salability as a percent.

So I want to do something like:

**Block** HGE 16 **Tree** Poplar Northwest; **Container** #2; **height range** 24 to 36 inches, **count** 216 **salable** 80%

where the bold words are 'markers'

Situation 2:  Blocks of variable sized larger trees.  For this I will have a height for each tree, as well as a condition.

So something like

**Tally**  Fin1 **Tree** White spruce  **Container** Grow bag #10

**Add** 1 **tree** five foot 3 **condition** prime

**Add** 1 **tree** 4 foot 9 **condition** good

**Add** 5 **tree** 5 foot zero **condition** good

**Add** 3 **tree** 3 foot 3 **condition** poor

**End Tally**

Can I do this on my phone with NO internet access?

Is there a way to do this from a recording made on the phone on my Mac?

Hardware:  Mac Pro 2012
OS Yosemite
iphone model MKQT2VC/A1688 (6s)

Edit:  I tried enabling dictation, but have siri disabled.  This seems to be working, although there are a lot of typos.  In particular homonyms.  E.g. one of my standard pots is a T2.  Sometimes it does T2, sometimes T to, sometimes tea too.  Sometimes a number is spelled out, sometimes just the number.

At present the 30 second interval seems to still be there.  I can do 3-4 items in that time.  This *may* work.

So at this point I'm looking for tips to make this work better.

Edit 2:  At temps of -7 I have about half an hour before the battery gets cold enough that the phone shuts down.  I have to keep it outside of my mitten because I have to restart dictation every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free ap through Google Play called EpiCollect. You only need GPS chip in phone, no data or cell. It will take location and you can fill in specifics on a menu you set up ahead of time.